# php contact form to display the email address of the sender in inbox

Tags: php, email

I would like to create a form that will simply allow the recipient of the messages the ability to click 'reply to' when responding to a website message from their inbox. The reply should auto populate with the sender's email address.

I think that I need to change the $mailheader from a specific email address to .$_POST, but my attempts are not working correctly. I feel like it must be something small that I am doing incorrectly.

Here is the php form code. It is working as is, but I am attempting to edit/improve usability:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$security = $_POST['security'];

$to = "website-owner@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Message from Website";
$message = "A visitor of exampledomain.com has submitted the following message.\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage: $message";
$mailheaders = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";


if ($security=="10") {
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$mailheaders);
    header("Location:contact.php?s=1");
}
else {
    header("Location:contact.php?s=2");
}
?>
```

This was my first attempt:

```
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\nReply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
```

This was my second attempt:

```
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "From: ".$_POST['Email']."\r\n";
```

This was my third attempt:

```
$mailheaders = "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheaders = "From: ".$_POST['Email']."\r\n";
```

Comment: I would suggest not changing the "from", but only the reply-to. Client or server security policies might not like your server to send emails with gmail.com or yahoo.com domain...even the mail relay you use to send it may not let them pass...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I found an answer to the question above.  This worked when the TO email was set to a gmail account, but it did not work when I changed it to domain based email account.  Do you have any suggestions on to how to get the email to pass through to the email inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! This mail header works.

```
$mailheaders = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```